# Why does the login.php keeps saying invalid password?

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a login page (login.php)

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: asdasd.php");
  exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, felhasznalonev, jelszo FROM diakok WHERE felhasznalonev = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: asdasd.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With that, I can login to accounts which are created by felvetel.php:

```
<?php
$teljes_nev = $_POST['teljes_nev'];
$kategoria = $_POST['kategoria'];
$felhasznalonev = $_POST['felhasznalonev'];
$idcske = "NULL";
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if (!$teljes_nev) {
  echo "Kérem írja be a diák nevét.";
  exit;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $teljes_nev = addslashes($teljes_nev);
  $felhasznalonev = addslashes($felhasznalonev);
  $jelszo_alap = rand(1000,9999);
  $jelszo = password_hash($jelszo_alap, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}

@ $adatbazis = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'diakok');
$adatbazis->set_charset('utf8');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Nem sikerült csatlakozni az adatbázishoz. (1-es hibakód)";
}

$lekerdezes = "INSERT INTO diakok VALUES
              ('".$felhasznalonev."', '".$teljes_nev."', '".$jelszo."', '".$kategoria."', '".$idcske."', '".$idcske."' , '".$idcske."' ,'".$idcske."', '".$idcske."')";
$talalat = $adatbazis->query($lekerdezes);
if ($talalat) {
  echo $teljes_nev." nevű diák sikeresen felkerült az adatbázisba! (A diák jelszava ".$jelszo_alap.")";
} else {
  echo "Hiba! A diákot nem sikerült hozzáadni az adatbázishoz.";
}

$adatbazis->close();

?>
```

My problem is that it says  "The password you entered was not valid." while I write the correct password.
For example, I created a test user called admin.pelda and its password without password_hash() is 2161. 
Now when I try to log in the account, it gives the invalid password message to me.
Any ideas to fix it?
(My config.php is okay)

Comment: In the database, I have felhasznalonev for username and jelszo for password.

Comment: debug.. place `var_dump("variable:" . $variable); exit();` on logical (before flowcontrol statements) locations in the code and see what happens as example `var_dump("password". $password); var_dump("hashed_password". $hashed_password); var_dump("password_verify(...)". password_verify($password. $hashed_password)); exit();` before using `password_verify($password. $hashed_password)`

Comment: Besides you should fix you SQL injection in the INSERT query, you should know how because you are using prepared statements for the SELECT..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, string(8) "password" string(4) "gtrg" string(15) "hashed_password" string(8) "admin123" is given by the var dump. If i get it right, the good password would be admin123. The problem is that if I write admin123, it also gives me invalid password.

Comment: What is the type of your 'jelszo' field in your database?

Comment: @M.Collins The hashed password cannot be "admin123", it has to be a hash value returned by `password_hash()`. Otherwise it won't work for `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the hashed password is really long, and in the database, the password's max length was set to 15.

Comment: `$jelszo = password_hash($jelszo_alap, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` -> "PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, **it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)**."  It's in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)